# Naturally sort IQueryable strings in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, natural-sort

I have a good way to sort data "naturally" with an `IComparer` similar to the answers @ [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp). In my case, I have a class that goes something like this:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a collection that reads as follows,

```
[{Id: 1, Name: "2 N. Street"},{Id: 2, Name: "33 N. Street"},{Id: 3, Name: "4 N. Street"}]
```

using an OData query like the following would return the data in the same order as above,

```
http://www.example.com/Widget.svc/GetWidgets?$orderby=Name
```

while I actually would like the data "naturally" ordered as such:

```
[{Id: 1, Name: "2 N. Street"},{Id: 3, Name: "4 N. Street"},{Id: 2, Name: "33 N. Street"}]
```

Is there a good way to customize a WCF service to make any query that tries to order by any string property to sort data "naturally"?

Comment: The best way to generally handle this that I've found is to provide an implementation of `IQueryable` that naturally sorts string columns. I'll provide an answer that spells this out in more detail if I can get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible via a pre-release NuGet package called [Buildium.ComparedQueryable](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Buildium.ComparedQueryable/).

```
Install-Package Buildium.ComparedQueryable -Version 0.1.3
```

Given you have an `IQueryable` stored in memory, calling `AsNaturalQueryable` on it would return the collection sorted naturally.

```
using ComparedQueryable;

public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Widget> widgets = this.service.GetWidgets();
    return widgets.AsNaturalQueryable();
}
```